# Slice a string starting from a word - MySql

Tags: mysql

I have a table product_info which contains a field called 'description'. There're some rows like 'blablabla sizes what-what'. Now I wanna slice out the actual sizes ('what-what') and put it in a new field called 'size'.

I tried this:

```
UPDATE product_info
SET size=SUBSTRING(description, "sizes"+1)
WHERE description LIKE '%sizes%';
```

It just doesn't seem to work -- it copied everything in description, the entire 'blablabla sizes what-what'. Can somebody help?

Comment: Substring param 2 should be an int..... so how is String+int == int?     See: http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-substring-function.php

Comment: "sizes" doesnt give you the index of word. Use `INSTR` funciton: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_instr to get the index of word "sizes"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

substring takes a string and a position  SUBSTRING(str,pos) but you are passing a string + 1 and only the gods know what value is passing.

What you need is use it in conjunction with INSTR

INSTR(str,substr) Returns the position of the first occurrence of substring substr in string str.

UPDATE product_info
SET size=SUBSTRING(description,INSTR(description,"sizes"))
WHERE description LIKE '%sizes%';

now 2 things to bare in mind.

1. your sizes rest of string is gone, you need to persist that before saying to this bye bye
2. I didn't test this throughly so I'm not sure what happens when there's no size, since INSTR will be returning 0

Comment: It worked, only minor error is that the INSTR() should be INSTR(description, "sizes"). Thanks bud!